# Merge [querystringparameter] and [queryparam] into [query-parameters]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Merge [querystringparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/querystringparameter) (145 questions) and [queryparam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryparam) (12) into [query-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-parameters) (446)?

All seem intended to tag the same thing: questions on [URL query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameters. Look through some questions with those tags and you'll see the context of all is in fact overwhelmingly that.

Comment: Or better yet, all of them into [query-string].

Comment: I would have expected query-parameters to run with SQL as well, which it does: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bquery-parameters%5D+sql Those need a clean-up first.

Comment: Imo [tag:query-parameters] might not be the best tag name, for the reason Rene said: It might be confused with [tag:parameterized-query] and [tag:sqlparameters]. In the tag name, it's hard to see your fault, and we all know people often forget to read the excerpt.

Comment: [QueryStringParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter?view=netframework-4.8) is a class in .Net. Does it still make sense to merge it into [tag:query-string] or should be disambiguated?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to disambiguate it