# Should [query-parameters] be merged into [query-string] and made a synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string) has 3,582 questions and the following [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-string/info):

> The part of a URL after the ? (question mark), containing parameter=value pairs separated by & (ampersand). In a request made to a web application at a particular URL, the parameter+value data in the query string is parsed/consumed by the web application on the backend that receives the request.
>
> See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

The tag [query-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-parameters) has 560 questions and the following [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-parameters/info):

> The part of a URL after the ? (question mark), containing parameter=value pairs separated by & (ampersand). In a request made to a web application at a particular URL, the parameter+value data in the query string is parsed/consumed by the web application on the backend that receives the request.
>
> See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

As you can see **their *About* pages are completely identical**.  Is there any reason for both to exist?  (And, like wearing both a belt and suspenders, [11 questions have both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string+query-parameters).)

There is already a tag [querystringparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/querystringparameter) (156 questions) for a *single* parameter in a query string; so [query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string) and [query-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-parameters) are both for the entire query string.

If there is no difference, I propose they be merged.  I don't have a strong sense of which name is better, but [query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string) is more popular, so it seems reasonable that one should be left standing.  (Neither name seems precise though since other technologies besides URLs have query strings.)

Since both are moderately popular, once they are merged a synonym should be created.

Note that in the related question *[Merge [querystringparameter] and [queryparam] into [query-parameters]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362184/3744182)*, rene raises the point there are 137 questions [matching `[query-parameters] sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bquery-parameters%5D+sql) so [query-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-parameters) may need some cleanup before the merge.